# Installing pgAdmin 4 separately on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've installed PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to install pgAdmin 4 on another Ubuntu box separately. Is it possible or any recommendation for that? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is very well possible.

On your database server, enable access over the network (in the `pg_hba.conf` file).

On the other system, install pgAdmin and use the [Server dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.x/server_dialog.html) to set up a connection to the database server.